# Django generics.ListAPIView accepting POST method

Tags: python, django, http

I have a Django view which extends `generics.ListAPIView`. It works fine with get requests, however since the char limits of the URL, now I need to send the request via POST. It is the same request, the only thing I need to change is the method to POST.
My current code is pretty simple:

```
class MyClass(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = MySerializer
paginate_by = 1

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = SomeClass.objects.all()
    # do some filtering
```

How could I add POST support to this class?

Comment: I am not shure if I understand you correctly, do you like to send a GET-request with the POST method, or dou you like to add POST-Methods to your class?

Comment: Using POST to retrieve records is contrary to REST specifications and would not be recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyClass(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = SomeClass.objects.all()
        # do some filtering


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [ListCreatAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) and overriede the `create` method to do same as your `list` method. Maybe you can just do something like the following:

```
class MyClass(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = SomeClass.objects.all()
        # do some filtering
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # maybe replace request.method with 'GET'
        self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I would suggest to use the methods as specified.